# How to add multiple copies of a widget from “available widgets”

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I've found a widget that I need to add to more than one sidebar widget area.

However, apparently its been coded so that once you drag it from "available widgets" over to a sidebar widget, it disappears from the "available widgets" listing.

here is the code from the functions.php

```
if (function_exists('register_sidebar')) {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Blog Widgets',
        'id'   => 'sidebar-widgets',
        'description'   => 'Widget Area',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="one" class="two">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2>',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>'
    ));
}
```

here is the code from my index.php

```
<p><?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Sidebar Widgets') ) : ?>
                    <?php endif; ?></p>
```

you help will appreciated

thank you

Comment: Does this apply to all widgets? if not which widget? What WordPress Version do you use? It it a custom theme? where did you get it?

Comment: its a custom theme, wordpress Version 3.5.1, when i duplicate the code I showed on the post, it just desappears

Comment: Your code has nothing to do with what widgets appear in available widgets. You could always just put that 1 widget in a sidebar on its own then include that sidebar in each of the templates that use that widget. You are not limited to a single sidebar on a template